# Number of different number of outcomes

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Let's say I roll a fair die $4$ times. What is the number of ways we have exactly $2$ different faces?

My try:

Filling four boxes such that two boxes take different values and the other two take any one of the values sitting in the first two boxes. So it is $6\times5\times2\times2$.

Is this correct? Help appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first two dice could show the same value, for example. Here are some hints at one method of solution.

There are $15=\binom 62$ ways of picking two values from the six available.

There are $2^4$ ways of allocating those two values to four dice.

There are $2=2\times 1^4$ of these ways which have the same value on all four faces.

Comment: So, the final answer is $\binom 62 (2^4 - 2)$?

Comment: @Lohith-kumar I left that for you to work out. You can also extend your computation to take account of the fact that second and third can be the same as the first $6\times 5 \times 2 \times 2+6\times 1 \times 5 \times 2+6\times 1\times 1\times 5$

Comment: Got the enumeration part. But it is tedious to achieve the solution to the bigger problem, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2496240/expected-number-of-different-outcomes.

Comment: In your method. There are $15$ ways to pick two distinct numbers. For each such picking there are (2^4 - 2) of them which are fitting to the requirement. Thus my first comment.